# Agregar contenido dinámico mediante jquery o javascript a partir de un botón

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy desarrollando un formulario y me gustaría replicar el contenido de la primera fila en la segunda, pero que esta se genere de forma dinámica mediante una función de javascript (onclick) o Jquery (click).
He leído que la forma correcta es guardar el código html en una variable como si se tratase de un string y luego ubicar mediante el uso del DOM el lugar donde se insertara el código utilizando la función append. Trate de hacerlo pero evidentemente no me ha funcionado y creo que se debe al uso de las comillas.

Adjunto a continuación el código que debería replicar y también para que se entienda mejor mi pregunta

```html
<div class="row container-fluid">
  <p class="text-muted" style="margin-left: 10px;">Datos Filiatorios</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textAseguradorMedico" class="control-label text-muted">Asegurador Medico</label>
      <select id="textAseguradorMedico" name="textAseguradorMedico" class="form-control selectpicker input-sm" onchange="validacion('textAseguradorMedico')">
        <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
        <option value="Particular" <?php if ($paciente->getObraSocial() == 'Particular') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Particular</option>
        <option value="Prepaga" <?php if ($paciente->getObraSocial() == 'Prepaga') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Prepaga</option>
        <option value="Obra social sindical" <?php if ($paciente->getObraSocial() == 'Obra social sindical') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Obra social sindical</option>
        <option value="Obra social para la atencion de monotributistas" <?php if ($paciente->getObraSocial() == 'Obra social para la atención de monotributistas') {echo 'selected';} ?>>Obra social para la atención de monotributistas</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <label for="textNombreObraSocial" class="control-label text-muted">Nombre</label>
    <select id="textNombreObraSocial" name="textNombreObraSocial" class="form-control selectpicker input-sm" onchange="" value="">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
    <label for="textPlanObraSocial" class="control-label text-muted">Plan Obra social</label>
    <input type="text" id="textPlanObraSocial" class="form-control input-sm" name="textPlanObraSocial" onkeyup="" value="" maxlength="60" placeholder="Plan de obra social.">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
    <label for="textFechaVencimiento" class="control-label text-muted">Fecha Vencimiento</label>
    <input type="date" id="textFechaVencimiento" class="form-control input-sm" name="textFechaVencimiento" data-date-format="MMMM YYYY" value="" onkeyup="" value="" min="" max="" maxlength="4">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
    <label for="textFechaVencimiento" class="control-label text-muted">Agregar</label>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="addObraSocial()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La función de javaScript que estoy utilizando para agregar dicho contenido seria (obviamente me gustaria agregar todo el código)

```
function addObraSocial(){
var html = '<div class="col-md-1 form-group"></div>';
$('#segundaObraSocial').append(html);
```

}

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay cosas que no me terminan de quedar claras en tu pregunta. ¿A qué llamas "primera fila"? En tu código veo solamente una **row** que básicamente es todo le HTML que has pegado. ¿Eso es lo que necesitas replicar? Esta pregunta me lleva a otra. ¿A qué te refieres con replicar? ¿Generar otra estructura HTML vacía para que el usuario pueda rellenarla o también necesitas que se duplique lo que el usuario ha rellenado en la primera?

Comment: Si por ahí no fui claro con el termino replicar, pero me refería a repetir ese bloque de código dos veces. Dado que el selector "#segundaObraSocial" apuntaría a la segunda fila donde iría todo el html que puse en mi ejemplo que básicamente seria partir del la etiqueta p en adelante hasta el ante ultimo div que se observa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me sigue sin quedar claro si necesitas replicar los valores que contienen los **input** y los **select** en el momento de dar al botón. Así que asumiré que lo que necesitas es una estructura **HTML** limpia en la que el usuario pueda "escribir".

Existen varias maneras para hacer esto, te voy a dar una de ellas, que además considero que es de las más simples:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var contador = $('.obra-social').length + 1;
 var bloque = '<div id="obra-social-' + contador + '" class="obra-social"><p>Contenido obra social</p</div>';
  $('#contenedor').append(bloque);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}

.obra-social {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div id="contenedor">
    <div id="obra-social-1" class="obra-social">
      <p>Contenido obra social</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <button>
    Añade obra social
  </button>
</div>
```

Lo que se suele hacer es tener almacenado en una variable un **string** con la estructura **HTML** a replicar para insertarla cómodamente donde desees. Una función útil para insertar contenido dinamicamente es, efectivamente, `append()`, de Jquery. Esta función inserta al final del selector que le indiques el contenido que le pases, en este caso tu estructura **HTML** creada con anterioridad.

Esto tiene un problema, ya que a la hora de manejar IDs, las estarías duplicando por cada vez que llamases a la función con el **click**. Para solucionar esto también tendrías que generar IDs, dinámicas.

Yo suelo contar el número de elementos de ese tipo que existen en el momento de hacer el **click**, y usar ese número para generar mis IDs.

En el código que te adjunto también te muestro un ejemplo de ello.

Comment: Claro si, no entendía a que te referías a una estructura html limpio, pero justamente era eso, es decir volver a tener por duplicado los imputs y select vacios para insertar nuevos datos en cada uno de ellos. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, tratare de adaptarlo a mi problema.